# putchar() function: ambiguous output

Tags: c, arrays, string, putchar

Here is a simple code , trying to clear spaces from character array, but output is not like I did expect "YasserMohamed".

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x[]="Yasser Mohamed";
    char ch;
    int i=0;
    while (x[i]!='\n')
    {
        if(x[i]!=' ')
            putchar(x[i]);
        i++;
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Consider Other Answe too for marking best answer.

Comment: the `system()` function requires the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  which the posted code is missing.

Comment: the `pause` shell command is not portable,   It is only found on windows.
a generic way to implement a similar functionality is: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() != EOF && '\n' != ch );  getchar();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *newline* (`'\n'`) in `x`. So, the condition is wrong and it should be:

```
while (x[i]) /* until the null byte is found */
{
    if (x[i] != ' ')
        putchar(x[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Note: It's more explicit to write `x[i] != '\0'` but could lead to write `x[i] != '0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your string in `x` does not contain the newline character `'\n'` that you use as a condition in the loop.

Use `while (x[i]!=0x00)` to end at the terminating `NUL` character (`0x00`).

Comment: "*Use `while (x[i]!=0x00)`*" or `while (x[i]!=0)` or `while (x[i]!='\0')` or just `while (x[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you never stopped the loop you wrote

```
while(x[i]!='\n')
    {
       //What You Want To Do.
           }
```

But `x[i]` was not `'\n'` for any `x[i]` defined.

It would work if you instead write it as `i!= 14`. Then Loop Would stopped at end of your name. Going Beyond is undefined as this not your variable memory region.

Or You Could also write `while(x[i])` as end of the string in C are Null-Terminated `\0` which evaluates to false, so loop would stop.

Correct Code Could Be

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {

     char x[]="Yasser Mohamed";
     char ch;
     int i=0;
     while (x[i])    //As Null Character '\0' evaluates to false it would stop the loop
     {
         if(x[i]!=' ')
             putchar(x[i]);
         i++;
     }
     system("pause");

     return 0 ;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `\n` in your original `x`, so you just continue iterating uninitialized memory until you happen to encounter `\n`. Instead, you should iterate up to the string terminating character - `\0`:

```
while (x[i] != '\0') {
// Here --------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 0 instead of '\ 0'(is exactly the same value), like that:

```
for (int i = 0; x[i] != 0; i++) {
    if (x[i] != ' ')
        putchar(x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a null character at the end of a null terminated string not a new line.

you should change `'\n'` to `'\0'` or 0(which is the ASCII code of null character).

```
 #include<stdio.h>


 int main()
 {

     char x[]="Yasser Mohamed";
     char ch;
     int i=0;
     while (x[i]!='\0')
     {
         if(x[i]!=' ')
             putchar(x[i]);
         i++;
     }
     system("pause");

     return 0 ;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
int main()
{
    char x[]="Yasser Mohamed";
    char ch;
    int i=0;
    while (x[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(x[i]!=' ') {
            printf("%c", x[i]); // replace putchar with printf
            fflush(stdout); // force character to appear
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n"); // print newline so shell doesn't appear right here
    return 0 ;
}
```

Strings are terminated with null `\0` characters not newlines.

Also, you should add an `fflush` statement (at least on linux) to make sure every character gets printed.

To make your output look nice, add a newline after the loop.

I replaced your `putchar` call with `printf` to see if that would help when I ran your program. `putchar` will likely also work fine.

I removed `system(pause)` because it didn't seem to help. I added a newline character print instead.